# Certificate issue after migrate from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: ios, html, https, iphone-web-app

I am working on mobile HTML5 site using HTML5/JQueryMobile and server is in php. I changed sever settings from `HTTP` to `HTTPS` but now from my mobile it shows these type of error

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “www.example.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.
```

when using in `IPhone 5` with `IOs 7.1.2`.

How to handle that issue. What things i have to do?

Comment: Hi downvoter. Can you please tell me reason for diwn vote maybe that reason leads me to my solution. I'll be grateful for your help

Answer (score 1):

For us this happened with the update to iOS 13. The requirements for trusted certificates changed, so we needed to adjust the certificate.

[See the official page of Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a self-signed certificate. Thus your iPhone doesn't trust your certificate.

Either add the certificate to your iPhone as a trusted certificate. (recommended)

Or create a official certificate from a trusted authority. (recommended for production usage)

Or make requests and allowing insecure (self-signed) certificates. (not really recommended, but might be the fastest solution)

Comment: When i first load my website it show me some kind of certifcate its from the server after i add that as trusted my web works 2,3 times and then again same error.
now i don't understand what a problem here

Comment: Do you get the same certificate request then? Maybe after clearing cache. And you did create a certificate on your own, because the certificate has to match the domain name you are requesting.

Comment: no it didn't show again. Also after clear cache. So i reset all my network setting after that it ask me again i add again like trust/Accept it make 3,4 api calls perfectly and than again show same error.

Comment: When you have to accept it again, it wasn't stored as trusted certificate, but merely session based trust.

Comment: i reset all my IPhone setting after that it ask me again. Before only cache refresh it didm;t ask again. But anyways api calls to server have that issue that it show the error.